# Show that $ \sum_{k=1}^n k n = \mathrm{O}(n^3)$

Tags: limits, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Cheers, I have to show that $ \sum_{k=1}^n k n = \mathrm{O}(n^3)$. It's a fairly easy question, but I need some answers as to that I am allowed to do.

The first way to solve this is pretty easy I think, so I stated:

$$n + 2n + 3n + \cdots + n \cdot n \leq \\ n \cdot n + n \cdot n + n \cdot n + \cdots n \cdot n = n \cdot n \cdot n = n^3 $$

so we proved it one way, basically.

Now I also tried to solve it using the limits. So I tried saying something like this:

We have to prove that: $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k n}{n^3} = 0$$

Now at this point, I have a question. Is this fraction even eligible to use L'Hopital's rule, and if yes how would that be applied? I am thinking that the limit would boil down to:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k n}{n^3} \stackrel{\frac{\infty}{\infty}(?)}{=} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k}{3n^2} = 0 $$

but I don't know If I am exactly allowed to even do that.

I also tried to split them, so I'd get:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n^3} + \frac{2n}{n^3} + \frac{3n}{n^3} + \cdots + \frac{n^2}{n^3} = 0 + 0 + 0 + \cdots + 0 = 0$$

Would that be a correct answer as well? Thanks for any help =)

Comment: You don't need to prove it's zero (actually it isn't). You don't even need to prove the limit exists, although it does. You just need the ratio to be bounded as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @Chris Sanders Where would the integration be applied here? Have I lost something?

Comment: @average_discrete_math_enjoyer try thinking about the formula for an integral as a limit of a riemann sum

Comment: Also, your logic in going from a limit of a sum to a sum of limits is not valid when the number of terms is dependent on the variable of the limit. You might want to look at Stolz-Cesaro, which is kind of similar to L'hopitals in spirit.

Answer (score 2):

Observe $\sum_{k=1}^{n}kn = n\sum_{k=1}^{n}k$. Then notice the following trick: let $S = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k$. Then
$$S = 1 + 2 + \cdots + n$$
but also
$$S = n + (n-1) + \cdots + 1\text{.}$$
Convince yourself that if we add the two equations above term by term, we have
$$S + S = 2S = \underbrace{(n+1) + (n+1) + \cdots + (n+1)}_{n \text{ times}} = (n+1)n$$
hence
$$S = \dfrac{(n+1)n}{2} = O(n^2)$$
therefore what can we say about $\sum_{k=1}^{n}kn = n \sum_{k=1}^{n}k= nS$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $n+2n+3n+\cdots+n^2=n(1+2+3+\cdots+n)$

Do you know a formula for the sum of the first $n$ naturals?

Comment: $n +2n+3n+...+n^2$

Answer (score 1):

We just need to understand $\sum_{k=1}^n k$.

The following is a common trick:

Think about how rectangles of width $1$ are used to approximate integrals.

If you draw this on a graph, you will soon realise that

$\int_0 ^{n-1} x\; \text{d}x<\sum_{k=1}^n k<\int_1 ^n x\; \text{d}x$.

This is the same as saying

$\frac{(n-1)^2}{2}< \sum_{k=1}^n k<\frac{n^2-1}{2}$.

$\\$

As an exercise, perhaps you might want to see if you can apply this to $\sum_{k=1}^n k^s$, for any positive $s$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} kn$. So

$$f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} kn = n\sum_{k=1}^{n}k = n(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}) = \frac{n^3+n^2}{2}.$$

Now we can choose $M = 1$ and $N = 1$ and so

$$n \ge N : |f(n)| \le n^3.$$

So $f(n) \in O(n^3).$